# ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=

Tags: python, django

I have used `with open` but no luck but I still get this error :

```
 ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='/home/idris/Documents/workspace/captiq/captiq/static/docs/CAPTIQ Datenschutzhinweise.pdf'>
  attachment=customer_profile.get_attachments(),
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

below is my function which the error points to :

```
def get_attachments(self):
       
        files = None
        cp = (
            self.cooperation_partner.get_cooperation_partner()
            if self.cooperation_partner else None)
        # TODO: improve implementation: too many conditions
        if cp and cp.custom_attachments.exists():
            files = [f.attachment for f in cp.custom_attachments.all()]
        elif cp and cp.pool.default_b2b_attachments.exists():
            files = [
                f.attachment for f in cp.pool.default_b2b_attachments.all()]
        else:
            files = self.get_default_attachments()
        if not files:
            path_one = finders.find(
                'docs/file_1.pdf')
            path_two = finders.find('docs/file_2.pdf')
            with open(path_one, 'rb') as f1, open(path_two, 'rb') as f2:
                files = [f1, f2]
                attachments = [
                    {
                        'filename': os.path.basename(attachment.name),
                        'content': attachment.read(),
                        'mimetype': mimetypes.guess_type(attachment.name)[0]
                    }
                    for attachment in files]
            return attachments

        attachments = [
            {
                'filename': os.path.basename(attachment.name),
                'content': attachment.read(),
                'mimetype': mimetypes.guess_type(attachment.name)[0]
            }
            for attachment in files]
        return attachments
```

So the issue is here with this section :

```
with open(path_one, 'rb') as f1, open(path_two, 'rb') as f2:
                files = [f1, f2]
                attachments = [
                    {
                        'filename': os.path.basename(attachment.name),
                        'content': attachment.read(),
                        'mimetype': mimetypes.guess_type(attachment.name)[0]
                    }
                    for attachment in files]
return attachments
```

Comment: Seems more likely that the problem is *not* in that section, and is in fact in the code path where you don't use `with` and don't do anything to close any files at all.

Comment: You mean thses lines : `path_one = finders.find(
                'docs/file_1.pdf')
            path_two = finders.find('docs/file_2.pdf')`

Comment: No. What do you think happens if the code does not go down the `if not files:` branch?

Comment: So what should I do here ? I use with open again ?

Comment: Any ideas to share?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the broader context of where those files are coming from, but just `close`-ing them in a `finally` block would be the quick-and-dirty way.